# Is it an error to say "Mi estas malvarma" when you mean "I feel cold"?

Tags: word-usage

In English, *I am cold* and *I feel cold* mean the same. In Esperanto, can we use "malvarma" for a feeling of the subject, or we have to say something like *Mi sentas malvarmon*? (In order to avoid confusion with *My internal temperature is low*.)

Comment: I would rather say *Mi sentas min malvarma*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not erroneous. *Mi estas malvarma* and *Mi malvarmas* are acceptable translations. (You will find that the sentence *Ĉu vi estas varmaj?* appears in Engholm's *Infanoj en Torento*.)

However, some people dislike it and consider it ambiguous: it might mean "I am a cold person" or "I am hypothermic" or something like that. (In particular, *Ich bin kalt/heiss* is inappropriate in German, and so native German-speakers are most likely to be bothered by it.) Therefore, alternative translations are:

- *Mi sentas min malvarma.* I feel [myself to be] cold.
- *Mi sentas malvarme.* I feel cold[ly].
- *Al mi estas malvarme. Al mi malvarmas.* It is cold for me.

Answer (score 5):

"Mi estas malvarma" would describe a property of you, that you are a cold person.

I recommend using the verb "frosti":

> Mi frostas.

For the opposite you can certainly say:

> Mi malfrostas.

although in my experience

> Estas al mi varme.

is more common.

Answer (score 1):

I've never received any complaints when I said it that way, but you bring up a good point about ambiguity. I'm almost certain that saying "Mi estas malvarma." **isn't** an error, but using "sentas" instead of "estas" is probably for the best, if only for clarity's sake.